# Graph API Facebook получить сообщения из переписки

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

С помощью Graph API получаю переписку пользователя
Запрос:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{id-member}/conversations?access_token={token}
```

Результат:

```
 "data": [
  {
     "id": "t_569662774172016",
     "link": "/messages/t/100033848963169/",
     "updated_time": "2021-09-19T21:44:02+0000"
  },
  {
     "id": "t_359209302409879",
     "link": "/messages/t/100066496846966/",
     "updated_time": "2021-08-30T05:11:32+0000"
  }
  ...
```

Пытаюсь получить сообщения из переписки следующим запросом:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/t_569662774172016?fields=messages&access_token=...
```

Выходит ошибка

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 't_569662774172016' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "AAQdj27Rj87OeEZkWOpf4gb"
}
```

Может кто имел дело с этим? Как получить сообщения из переписки?